# jQuery hover over item and keep active

Tags: jquery

I'm not really sure how to word this best, but basically I would like to hover over a list item which fades in another element right above it. When you hover back off the list item the elements should fadeout, but if you over hover the newly visible element, I would like it to remain visible.

I've put together a simple demonstration, http://jsfiddle.net/CLDyc/ - Basically, when you hover over item 1 and then move your mouse to "Item 1 Extra Info" I would like it also to stay visible.

```
var location;

$("#dots li").hover(

    function () {
        location = $(this).attr("class");
        $("#extra-info ."+location).fadeIn("fast");
      },
    function () {
        $("#extra-info ."+location).stop(true, false).fadeOut("fast");
      }
);
```

Comment: Maybe start a timeout when the mouse leaves item1, when the timeout ends have a function executed, which checks if the mouse is inside the item 1 extra info, if not hide it.

Comment: If the elements touch; the easiest method is to make the extra-info a child of the parent element. Similar with drop-downs, highlight <li> and it drops down a hidden <ul> - You can absolute position it outside of the parent container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there is a gap between the elements, `mouseleave` event is triggered and your element will be hidden, one option is using `setTimeout` function.

```
var location, timeout = 0;

$("#dots li").hover(function () {
    location = $(this).attr("class");
    $("#extra-info ." + location).fadeIn("fast");
}, function () {
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        $("#extra-info ." + location).stop(true, false).fadeOut("fast");
    }, 500);
});

$('#extra-info li').mouseenter(function(){
   clearTimeout(timeout);   
}).mouseleave(function(){
   $(this).fadeOut('fast');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SB4pH/

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to achieve it, similar to Syon's suggestion.

http://jsfiddle.net/CLDyc/2/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="dots">
    <li class="item1">Item 1<div style="display:none;">Item 1 Extra Info</div></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.item1 div {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position:absolute;
    top:8px;
    left:70px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;    
}

ul#dots {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul#dots li {
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

**JS**

```
$("#dots li").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find('div').stop(true, false).fadeIn("fast");
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).find('div').stop(true, false).fadeOut("fast");
});

$(".item1 div").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).stop(true, false).show();
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).stop(true, false).fadeOut("fast");
});
```